# vsftpd not honouring userlist_enabled

Tags: ubuntu, vsftpd, ubuntu-22.04

I have a vsftp server with this configuration running in ubuntu 22.04:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/<hidden>
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/<hidden>
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_min_port=60000
pasv_max_port=60002
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
```

I expected the vsftp server to allow access only to users in `/etc/vsftpd.userlist` but it allows access to any local user.

I tried `local_enable=NO`. It didn't have any effect.

`/etc/vsftpd.userlist`contains only two users.

Any idea?

Comment: You did, of course, restart the service after changing `local_enable=NO`?

Comment: yes, I did, of course, restart the service after I changed the configuration, @tsc_chazz.

Comment: That's curious. `vsftpd.conf` man page says local_enable "This must be enable for any non-anonymous login to work, including virtual users. " I'm clutching at straws here, but is it possible that the `conf` file you're changing is not the one that `vsftpd` is looking for? Default is `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` but might check to see if that's changed by whatever is launching the service.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @tsc_chazz. I had the same suspicion, I checked in /lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service and the config file is the correct one.

Comment: Add the following line to your /etc/vsftpd.conf "userlist_deny=YES" To ensure that the userlist restriction is applied.

Answer (score 1):

The default file is `/etc/vsftpd.user_list` (notice the underscore), while you specified `/etc/vsftpd.userlist` (without underscore).

Please restore the default location by removing the line with `userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist` and be sure your user list file under `/etc` to be named `vsftpd.user_list` (with the underscore).

Then restart the `vsftpd` service.

Comment: That didn't work. And also, `userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist` should override the file location, it should not be constrained to the default location.

Comment: It depends on the applied AppArmor profile - it can enforce a specific filename, hence my suggestion to use the default one